# Is there a difference between preference order and preference relation and if yes, what?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

While reading about utility theory (in context of Game theory) I came across two terms: preference order and preference relation. I am not clear about the distinction between them. Reference Link: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5846/2017sp/2%20utility.pdf

Comment: They are pretty much used synonymously. But the terminology is not completely unified, so you have to check which definition is used exactly.